# Why do most manufacturers recommend curing resin models before removing supports?

Tags: resin, post-processing

Why do manufacturers such as Elegoo always recommend that you cure your resin 3D prints before removing the supports, while hobbyist such as Uncle Joey usually recommend that you soak your models in warm water and remove the supports while they are soft, prior to curing?

Is there a firm and quantifiable reason for this difference, or does it purely come down to personal preference?

Comment: Just a guess, but manufacturers are probably looking at safety concerns vs hobbyists that are looking at practicality and workability.

Comment: If you care about dimensional accuracy, you probably want to cure them before putting stresses on them by pulling at supports.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that Resin manufacturers recommend this for two reasons:

1. Uncured resin is not safe to handle, and support removal requires handling and manipulating the part. Curing the part removes this safety implication, making support removal less likely to expose you to uncured resin via mechanical means and/or accidentally breaking your gloves with the tools for support removal.
2. Uncured parts are still malleable and prone to squishing or deforming under force. Curing parts will make them firm and insusceptible to deformation while attempting to remove support material.

However, Modern support patterns have become significantly easier to remove, Making it more of a personal preference rather than one with any merit behind it. Most recommend removing support material before curing as the 2nd point above can be taken advantage of to remove supports specifically, whilst keeping parts intact and accurate.